# Total Power Dissipation - Design Margin

Tags: power, semiconductors

It is good practice to ensure some design margin for the electronic circuit in terms of absolute maximum ratings.

What is the proper way of selecting such a margin for Total Power Dissipation?

Let's assume 20% as a safety margin for any reason and SOT363 NPN Transistor as an example:

On the chart below there is a common power derating curve for BC847 NPN Transistor in SOT363 Package - **[Blue]**.

I calculated the -20% Power alternative **[Green]** it looks good however the closer we get to the Absolute Maximum Temperature Rating [150C] the smaller the margin becomes. This is why I wonder if it is a proper way of doing this?

As an alternative, I added another line which is basically -10C of the base the value **[Green]**.

Is there a way to define something "in-between"?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that curve is accurate without knowing the PCB thickness, weight, and footprint it's mounted on.

Comment: As well as any margin calculations people advise - note that graphs are usually "typical
 ratings unless otherwise specified. Look at tabled specs to get some idea of how much typical and max and min values compare.

Comment: For the Thermal characteristics, the Maximum thermal resistance values are defined, so it should not be worse than what I presented here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have never done MTBF calculations before there is a general failure rate acceleration factor that often doubles for every 10'C rise (Arhennius Law).

My criteria for a commercial design when I managed this function, was 85'C for junction temperature at maximum ambient of 40'C normally operated at room temp.

- package thermal resistance, Rjs = 230'C/W from junction to solder point
- FR4 Rsa= 338'C/W   from solder point ambient with free moving air, while sealed air is worse and adding 1 cm^2 exposed copper to collectors reduces by 20'C/W per cm² area of collector copper
  [image: ²]